# Paperclip - Upload from URL rather than a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm in the process of migrating a set of files from an old Drupal application to a Rails app.

Using paperclip, I want to upload a file to this model:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :video_file
end
```

But I want to upload the file from a URL in code rather than using a form.

Apparently since Paperclip 2.1.4, you are able to do this like so:

`video.video_file = URI.parse('http://path/to/video.mp4')`

When I run this, there is a noticeable delay while the file is downloaded but none of the fields for the file are populated and the file has not been uploaded. What step am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
video.video_file = File.open("http://path/to/video.mp4")
```

Comment: Thanks but it throws this error: `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen`. The file is on a remote location.